# RevTex 4.2 Two-Column Journal Formatting for AIP

Tags: two-column, revtex

I am in the process of writing a paper for submission in AIP Physics of Fluids journal. I am using the RevTex 4.2 distribution to get their formatting, but I am unable to reproduce how the final document will be displayed. From my understanding, in order to see how my document will look like in journal formatting, I need to use the option reprint with two column formatting:

`\documentclass[reprint,aip,pof,amsmath,amssymb,twocolumn]{revtex4-2}`

However, this still displays as one-column. I've tried switching to the preprint option, and it works in displaying two-column mode, but it lacks the final formatting of the journal, which is what I want to see. I use MikTex and I believe I installed RevTex correctly by copying the required folders to my MikTex local directory, and everything compiles fine, except for this issue.

This is my code (I omitted some first-page entries which should not make any difference):

```
\documentclass[reprint,aip,pof,amsmath,amssymb,twocolumn]{revtex4-2}

\usepackage{graphicx}                                   % Include figure files
\usepackage{dcolumn}                                    % Align table columns on decimal point
\usepackage{bm}                                         % Bold math
\usepackage[group-separator={,}]{siunitx}               % SI units

\draft % marks overfull lines with a black rule on the right

\pdfoutput=1 % allows pdf output for LaTex compiler (instead of pdfLatex)

\begin{document}

\title{Title of Paper} %Title of paper

\date{\today}

\begin{abstract}
insert abstract here 
\end{abstract}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If I do that, it works on getting the formatting I want. However, I get two warnings saying I did not specify a society nor a journal, and it uses the defaults, which aren't the ones I want. I specifically want the american institute of physics' (aip)  physics of fluids journal (pof). It specifically says to use the `aip` option together with the journal I want to use in the user guide for aip, available, for example in: https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/contrib/revtex/doc/aip/aipguide4-2.pdf

Comment: aip is the society (american institute of physics) and pof if physics of fluids journal

Comment: Can you provide a link to the manual you're referring to? The one I sent on the previous comment has the pof option in table I (page 2).

Comment: Only revtex4.1 seems to come with a manual (user guide).  See https://ctan.org/pkg/revtex4-1.

Comment: The society (aip) MUST be the first option.  It seems the journal should be the second option, but it also seems `reprint` should be second.  For example, `reprint` sets the font size (which should be third).  BTW, the reason I couldn't find `aip` is that it is used as a filename `aip4-2.rtx`.  The reason I couldn't find `pof` is that my editor doesn't search rtx files.

Comment: I see, but I've tried playing around with the order (aip,pof,reprint) or (aip,reprint,pof) and every one of these produces a one-column formatted document, despite having the twocolumn class assigned. Maybe it's a bug on revtex 4.2, as it doesn't happen in 4.1

Comment: Bug sounds good to me.

Comment: Is this issue solved? How?

Comment: The `aip` document class option necessarily prints a one-column document. You can see that in the `.log`: `AIP Info: pof journal style Single column, 2011/08/11` So the question currently seems to ask for something that contradicts the requirement. Unless you switch to a different journal/format, but that's what they (the journal) seems to require for submission.

Answer (score 0):

In RevTex 4.2 `twocolumn` format in the document class should work. If it does not work, cueck out the type of journal you are inputting/using - second input in the code below.

For instance, Physical Review Letters which is *prl*, see the example below:

```
 \documentclass[%
 aip,
 prl,%
 amsmath,amssymb,
%preprint,%
 reprint,%
%author-year,%
%author-numerical,%
twocolumn,
]{revtex4-2}
```